# Connect silex 2 dbal connect app engine with cloud sql

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, silex, dbal

I lost several hours trying to connect to cloud SQL from PHP flex env, but I found the answer.

I hope this help other people.

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

or

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsql' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- enable Google Cloud SQL API: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/

[image]

2.- get your cloud sql instance name

[image]

3.- add the beta_settings to your yaml

```
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "here-your-instance-name"
```

4.- config your doctrine dbal unix_socket

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'dbs.options' => array (
        'db_conn' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'unix_socket' => '/cloudsql/here-your-instance-name',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'dbname'    => 'your-database',
            'user'      => 'your-user',
            'password'  => 'your-password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collate'   => 'utf8_spanish2_ci'
        )
    )
));
```